# Condition inside Django filter

Tags: python, django

I'm having a trouble on how can I translate my query to Django format, The problem is I'm wondering if it is possible to have a if clause inside Django queries, So I have this format ,Im new inf filtering in Django, Is there idea how can I filter this format?

> query filter

```
SELECT paid_by, IF(paid = 'Yes' || paid = 'YES', 'paid', 'unpaid') as paided, category, category_status, count(paid) FROM `app_person`
```

> What I tried

```
app_person.objects.filter(IF(paid = 'Yes' ||paid = 'YES', 'paid', 'unpaid')as 'paided', 'category', 'category_status', 'count(paid)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Q` lookups for complex queries. Import `from django.db.models import Q`.

```
app_person=app_person.objects.filter(Q(paid = 'Yes') | Q(paid = 'YES'))
```

If you wish to use "Not Equal" or opposite of "IF", try this:

```
app_person.objects.filter(~Q(paid = 'Yes'))
```

Then, to change the status, i.e. "Paid" for attribute `paid`. Do this:

```
app_person.update(paid="Paid")
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but the thing is, I want to change the value if the paid value is equal to 'YES' for example if paid = `Yes` then paid value will turn to `Paid` can it possibly apply using Q lookups?

Comment: To update the attribute you can do it like I've mentioned in the answer after the edit. Notice, that `app_person` is a variable storing the queryset.

Comment: thanks for your response I tried this  `for p in Person.objectsf.filter(Q(paid = 'Yes')):
            p.update(paid="Paid")`  but it keeps telling me thiss error``AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'update'``